# Dynamically scale scene/USDZ file to plane?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

Currently, my app is tracking for an image. Once found, it places the 3D model right on top of it. My question is: is it possible to scale the USDZ/scene file to the plane automatically?

I'm currently tracking a postcard (5X7 in) and I want the model to simply sit on the postcard once detected (pretty small compared to most of my 3d models). I’m currently having to manually go in each file and scale it, but that’s taking a lot of manual time.

I figured there would be an easier way to programmatically scale the model, but not sure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            
            let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
            
            guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else {
                print("No images available")
                return
            }
            
            configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages
            configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 7
            
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        }
    

//MARK-:CODE WHERE I PLACE MY 3D MODEL

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
            
            let node = SCNNode()
            
            if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
                let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

                plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)

                let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
                planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

                guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hamburguer", withExtension: "usdz") else { fatalError() }
                let mdlAsset = MDLAsset(url: url)
                let shipScene = SCNScene(mdlAsset: mdlAsset)
//                let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "retro.scn")!
                let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!

                shipNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
                shipNode.position.z = 0.15

                planeNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
                
                node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            }
            return node
        }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something like the following:

```
    let width     = 10 //calculate the length of the target image
    let nodeWidth = shipNodeLength //calcualate the length of the original model
    if width > 0 {
        if nodeWidth > width {
            scale = width/nodeWidth
        } else {
            scale = nodeWidth/width
        }
    }
    
    shipNode.scale = SCNVector3(scale, scale, scale)
```

Comment: Hi @brockhampton! It's a good and common practice here, on StackOverflow, to upvote an accepted answer. Sorry saying that, but I see no one upvoted answer (upper arrow).

Comment: I just did. Thank you